# Typescript Propagating Generic Type Constraints

Tags: typescript, generics, functional-programming

Given a generic type:

```
export interface Mappable<Type, Src> {
    map: <T = Type, D = Src>(f: (a: Src) => D) => T;
}
export type ComposeMapper<T extends Mappable<A, B>, A, B> = (f: (a: B) => B, m: T) => T;
```

Why can't I use it in a declaration like so:

```
// Error: '(' expected
let _cm: <T extends Mappable> ComposeMapper<T>(f, m) => T;
```

But I can inline the type to declare it like this:

```
const _cm: <T extends Mappable<A ,B>, A, B>(f: (a: B) => B, m: T) => T = (f, m) => m.map(f);
```

Are generic types in type signatures expected to be right next to the parameter list, and can't be applied to another type?

Comment: Here's the simplified js code: `const compMap = (f, m) => m.map(f)` - it is curried with lodash in my app code, but I omitted that for brevity (in typescript I use `_cm` and then `const compMap = curry(_cm)` since lodash's curry is typed so I get all my types flowing out of the curry call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problematic declaration looks like you're trying to create a [generic variable](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574), but TypeScript (as of v2.5) doesn't have those.  TypeScript has generic *types*, which is what `ComposeMapper<T>` is, and it has generic *functions*, which is what your last `_cm` declaration is.

I'm confused about your typings though, anyway.  `Mappable` is an interface with a generic function `map()` that returns any type `T` that the caller of `map()` specifies?  How would that be implemented?  And the generic variable you want seems to return the *value* `T`, which is only a *type*, so that would be a syntax error anyway.  And the last line, where you are calling `m.map(f)` where `m` is a `T` and it returns a `T`?  How would you implement that?  I am very confused and I expect that you are also.  My only recommendation is for you to flesh out what you're trying to do and maybe implement it in JavaScript without types, and then see if you can use TypeScript to annotate it.  Or, possibly, spend more time reading [the generics section of the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)?  Not sure.

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Yeah my new typing for `Mappable` gets a little... crazy. I'll update with new typings.

Comment: You are correct in saying I need a generic variable though. Accepted for that! I'm basically making little typings to get by until folktale [releases their typings](https://github.com/origamitower/folktale/blob/bfeee814431a3aac4c3af94cec6e78fe78cc5a05/packages/base/index.d.ts) in the next release, but I wanted a way to easily compose functions together regardless of the algebra I was in (Result/Task), so I wrote this helper function and curried it so it can be used in a composition call.

Comment: [Here's a gist of more context](https://gist.github.com/snewell92/ff7a0b2482293cbd785879fe80f4587a) to answer more of the questions you posed to me.